# Why does this trigger make updates so slow?

Tags: mysql, triggers

when I update 100 records from the table with the trigger enabled it takes 15 seconds to execute, but when I run it without the trigger it takes only 2.

That's on the local development version, on the production one it takes two minutes. Is there any way I can speed it up?

Thanks.

```
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS imuebles_update;
  DELIMITER |
  CREATE TRIGGER imuebles_update AFTER UPDATE ON imuebles
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    IF NEW.pub_id IS NULL THEN
      DELETE FROM search_engine WHERE id = NEW.idImuebles;
    ELSE
      REPLACE INTO search_engine SELECT * FROM search_engine_v WHERE id = NEW.idImuebles;
    END IF;

  END;
  |

  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Check the query plans for the queries in the trigger to ensure that you have the appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to me it looks like,

```
REPLACE INTO search_engine SELECT * FROM search_engine_v WHERE id = NEW.idImuebles;
```

is potentially a pretty heavy duty thing to run on each row after an update.

My guess is that it would require a good look at why this is required rather than being a simple fix.

If you post some database structure information, perhaps somebody can suggest how to fix it.

Comment: You are right, that line does a select on a view that joins a lot of tables and that's why it's slow.